# Update Firebase Firestore Data After A Certain Amount of Time

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, schedule

I want to update a field of my firestore insert after a specific amount of time after it was created. I searched for several possibilities and came up with cloud functions. Unfortunately, java script isn't as easy for me to understand in order to write that function. In addition I red, there isn't a possibility to execute code after a amount of time, anyway.

So how can I handle that problem without writing a lot of js code and paying for the use of that function. Maybe a second application which is just a periodic timer and checks the DateTime field again and again. (Would be possible for me to run that application 24/7)

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a cloud function which triggers when a document is created. You can use timers like `setTimeout()` to execute a function which changes the document.

Look at the sample code below:

```
function updateDoc(id) {
    admin.firestore()
    .collection('Orders')
    .doc(id)
    .update({status: 2})
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Document ID: "+id+" successfully updated!");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
    });
}

exports.updateField = functions.firestore
    .document('/Orders/{id}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        console.log(context.params.id);
        const id = context.params.id;
        setTimeout(() => updateDoc(id), 600000);
    });
```

Here's the logs when I executed the function above.
[image: Firebase Function Logs]

You may want to check [Cloud Firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) for other triggers and [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) for other timeout options that you can use in your use-case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have a question. Isn't the running time of firebase functions limited to 60s? Will setTimeout work with that?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ahYpyW40 -  Tried it with this kind of code and always get the error "Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value" or "Exception from a finished function: Error: Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string."

Comment: @Thoxh , I've already updated my answer. Remove the `.bind` on your `setTimeout()`. Also I already used ES6 format on my updated answer `setTimeout(() => updateDoc(id), 600000);`. If you're planning to use commonJS format, this should work: `setTimeout(updateDoc(), 600000, id); `. If you can see on the code above, I already tried to `setTimeout()` to 10mins and works on my end.

Comment: Just a note: You would still get a message: `Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value` on my updated code. We're not returning any from the triggered function function because we delayed the call of the `updateDoc` function. You can return something on the trigger if you want to remove that message.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB can I set the timeout also to 3hours?

Comment: Using the timeout-function affects the performance of your cloud functions. Create a scheduled function instead.